# Thread.yield() in a Hyperthreading CPU

Tags: java, multithreading

The `Thread.yield()` static method (in Java) causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

If more than one thread is executing (in a CPU with hyperthreading functionality), which thread will pause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one that called `Thread.yield`...

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a misconception about HT, HT is handled by the hardware but requires a thread to be scheduled by the OS. If a thread yields the CPU it immediately halts its timeslice and the OS will place a new thread in its place (or the idle process). The other thread will continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java perspective, threads on a hyperthreaded CPU are not qualitatively different to threads running on different cores.  (They are just slower ...)

However, you are probably misunderstanding what `yield` does.  It does not guarantee to pause the current thread.  Rather it is just a hint to the thread scheduler to run a different thread now.

- If there is no other runnable thread, then the scheduler will immediately continue the thread that just yielded.
- The scheduler *may* decide to ignore the hint.

If you want / need the current thread to really pause, call `sleep` or block waiting for some event to occur.